# Can a dedicated GPU use/share system RAM in addtion to the VRAM included with it?

Tags: macos, memory, graphics-card, gpu

The Macbook Pro laptop, running OS X, has a AMD GPU which includes VRAM of 256 MB. Is it possible for the machine to run an application that requires 512 MB video memory by sharing some of the system RAM?

(There is also an integrated graphics card but this has a max (shared) VRAM of around 400 MB. AFAIK it cannot go over this.)

Comment: yes, Windows does this. Run ProcessExplorer, go to sytem information and uder GPU you see the dedicated RAM + system RAM usage.

Comment: Thanks. Any idea if OS X does too? I am updating the question to include this, didn't know it would be OS dependent.

Comment: ok, I have no idea because I don't use and will never use an Apple product. Also add the OS version tag

Comment: Done. I use Ubuntu, Windows and OS X ;) why don't/won't you ever use an Apple product?

Comment: I don't like all Apple the products at all.